# Access ng-repeat's item scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a table with rows that use their respective scope variables for conditional rendering:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
  <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="row.smth"/>
```

so that input is only shown when row scope variable `editMode` is set to true, it works perfectly fine.

Now I'd like to add another row dynamically:

```
$scope.data.push(my_new_row)
```

That works great too. But then I'd like to set that new row's scope variable `editMode` to something, and I'm out of ideas.

I know there's an undocumented way to use $$childHead etc but that's not very elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track items using $index. You can also use the index to decide to show/hide an item. You can do this by implementing a function with the show/hide logic and pass in the index. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in data track by $index">
    <input type="text" data-ng-show="GetEditMode($index)" ng-model="row.smth[$index]">
</div>
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/).

Comment: actually I had unique ID as part of my rows so `track by` wans't needed, just converted editMode to a function, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can set edit mode in row data.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-show="row.editMode" data-ng-model="row.smth"/>
```

or

you can try this :

```
<input type="text" data-ng-show="this.editMode" ng-change="toggle(this);" data-ng-model="row.smth"/>
```

In  Controller you can access editMode as:

```
$scope.toggle = function(context){
        console.log(a);
        context.editMode=!context.editMode;
}
```

Comment: my row data is right now just a plain data object from the server side, so I would have to introduce some filtering before sending back to server, it doesn't seem like a very good approach... I'm sure there must be a way to access row scope